# Unable to connect to webserver from outside

Tags: 12.04, apache2, connection, webserver

I set up my [website](http://www.syntaxarts.com) und my webserver but I'm facing the problem that the website cannot be opened from the internet. I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04 with Apache 2.2 (I believe). This is what I checked so far:

- `http://localhost/` responds with my website
- Firewall: port 80 open for incoming and outgoing traffic
- ports.conf -> listen 80
- Virtual host in httpd.conf is configured
- Port forwarding is enabled in the router configurations
- When the firewall is disabled and I ping the domain, I get my external IP
- http://www.canyouseeme.org/ doesn't see open port 80
- ISP doesn't seem to block incoming traffic on port 80
- Domain name is linked to my IP

Still, no connection to the server can be established. What did I forget?

Comment: No idea what it was, but now at least the port 80 seems to be open for http://www.canyouseeme.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add forwarding for 8888 port to yourmachine:80 and check it from the internet.
I had problems with forwarding if the router has web interface on the 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your router isn't using port 80 as well for management.  Try changing the webserver's port as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have the same problem with my router as [Yannick in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456441/setting-up-apache2-webserver-differences-between-behaviour-within-my-intranet). It is not possible to access the page within my intranet. The only option for now would be using some proxy website. Thanks tho.

Comment: I believe Yannick said you just need NAT loopback capability on your router. DDWRT has this http://lifehacker.com/how-to-supercharge-your-router-with-dd-wrt-508138224 and http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Comment: I think its not necessary. I think I can do almost everything using localhost (and proxy service for some corner cases).